# Git is not recognised despite being installed

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I mostly use https://github.dev because most of my commits are done in school using a school-controlled personal laptop (yeah my parents paid for it, but they put Intune on it for 4 years). Recently, they allowed for Visual Studio Code and Git to be installed. I was happy and decided to install it. Got my profile imported, but [Source Control shows I need to install Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih71c.png). [I already have it installed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGbSE.png).

The `Download Git for Windows` button doesn't launch Chrome and pressing `troubleshoot` does nothing.

I then try to Sign in with Github. [It remains in this state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g8f6.png).
Also [got this error from GitLens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUv5x.png) when launching VSCode

I tried to reinstall Git and VSCode, but that did nothing
I ran Visual Studio Code as Administrator, but [it stayed in a crash loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evCTr.png)

Any fixes available?

Comment: Make sure that its (Git) executable is included in the system's PATH environment variable. Sometimes, even if Git is installed, Visual Studio Code may not recognize it if it's not in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that its executable is included in the system's PATH environment variable. Sometimes, even if Git is installed, Visual Studio Code may not recognize it if it's not in the PATH.

If it's not:

Add the directory path where Git is installed (e.g., C:\Program Files\Git\bin) to the list of paths **"Environment Variables"**.

Note: Make sure to separate each path with a semicolon if there are multiple paths listed.

Comment: Worth knowing: in Windows 11, there now is a dedicated "Edit environment variables for your account" control panel you can access from the Start menu, which gives you a UI with one line per path, rather than having to manually manauge the semicolons.

Comment: Also after updating environment variables, the applications that require them should be restarted (i.e. close VSCode and open again)

Comment: @jepozdemir yeah I just set up the environment variables [image](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1162327891099537468/1218044659054547095/image.png?ex=66063b7c&is=65f3c67c&hm=2f523f846c0bb4efb8ee3b9366ff4dfe8c106bf99f9088acfdc3d589b512f12b&=&format=webp) but it still is showing the same error after restarts